# Migration with EF Core Collation Error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I have several tables with columns referencing the standard 
asp.net core AspNetUsers Column. That worked without problems, but now i added a new Table and all over sudden I get an error when trying to add my new table:

> Column 'xyz.AspNetUsers.Id' is not of same collation as
>   referencing column 'Device.LastModifiedById' in foreign key
>   'FK_Device_AspNetUsers_LastModifiedById'.

Everything is created code-first with EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.1 (Tools 1.1.0), execept a different schema (modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("xyz") I use all standard-values, and did not change anything with Collations.

Has somebody had a similar issue?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Narf, turned out I had restored my DEV-Database earlier from Production-Database... and simply missed selecting the proper Collation as Database-Default.